2018: a year in moderation
It's New Year's Day in Stack Exchange land...
A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
-- A Theory of Moderation

While there certainly are Moderators here, a significant amount of the moderation is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.
As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Bricks breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  0          5
Users destroyed                                   3          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            83        174
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                2          4
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         65         29
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               72         14
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               214        138
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               13         46
Tag synonyms proposed                             2          0
Tag synonyms created                              2          0
Questions reopened                                2          0
Questions protected                               4          4
Questions merged                                  1          0
Questions flagged⁴                                1        150
Questions closed                                 34          5
Question flags handled⁴                          16        135
Posts undeleted                                   0          6
Posts locked                                      1         25
Posts deleted⁵                                  108         82
Posts bumped                                      0         32
Comments flagged                                  1        181
Comments deleted⁶                               148        223
Comment flags handled                            71        111
Answers flagged                                   1        181
Answer flags handled                            157         25

Footnotes
¹ "Community" here refers both to the membership of Bricks without diamonds next to their names, and to the automated systems otherwise known as user #-1.
² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.
³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.
⁴ Includes close flags (but not close or reopen votes).
⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.
⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).
Wishing you all a happy new year...

Cheers Shog9, Happy New Year to you too ;)
